# secure communication with elasticsearch over java api

Tags: security, elasticsearch

I want to secure communication between Elasticsearch cluster and java (or any other api based) applications accessing it, but I didn't found any recommended way to do that. I have tried elasticsearch-jetty plugin and found it useful for user access over port 9200, but communication over port 9300 can't be secured and authenticated with it.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956062/authentication-in-elasticsearch and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21180716/securing-elasticsearch?rq=1