# Heroku + Amazon EC2 Security groups

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-ec2

So i have read many things about connecting Heroku Django App to my Amazon EC2 (which will serve as an external API to my site) and most of the solution were not free or not advised anymore.
I have 2 problems.

1 - Basically my problem is related to Amazon's security groups, where i need to add a static IP to allow external connection's into amazon. The problem is that Heroku's dynos are dynamic, and to make them static i need a NON FREE add-on, something like Prometheus for example. 
I was looking for a free solution. Any ideas on what i can do to achieve that?

2 - Amazon EC2 instances have dynamic Ips also, whats the best solution (free) to be able to have static ips so i can give to my Heroku app and tell it to always connect to that API sitting on amazon ec2?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no way to reliably have static IPs for your dynos. You'll have to do in this case with out firewall-level security (meaning, opening up your relevant ports for `0.0.0.0/0`, and make sure that you have proper authentication mechanisms for your API, such that no malicious user can gain access to your data. Most web frameworks support this out of the box, or have modules for API authentication (oauth comes to mind.)
2. Amazon EC2 IPs **are** static. You can request for a new IP and attach it to a running instance. Unless explicitly detached and released, it will remain static for as long as the instance is alive.

Comment: thanks @yuval-adam just one more question. about the first question, i actually have a direct connection to my elastic search db (using haystack) im not sure i can add authentication in that way. do you know how i can protect myself against that?

Comment: @psychok7 Lots of options discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956062/authentication-in-elasticsearch